# Vertx throws "Response has already been written" IllegalStateException

Tags: java, vert.x

So, i'm learning how to use vertx right now, and I'm trying to serve an html file on a get request. When I actually do the request on my localhost, it serves the file, but in my console I get the error:

**IllegalStateException: Response has already been written**

Here is my code:

```
package com.techprimers.vertx;

import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerResponse;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Route;

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        Route indexRoute = router
                .get("/")
                .handler(routingContext -> {
                    HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
                    response.setChunked(true);
                    response.sendFile("frontEnd/index.html");
                    response.end();
                });
  httpServer
                .requestHandler(router::accept)
                .listen(8000);

    }
}
```

And my file tree looks like this:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks

Comment: everything works fine!

Comment: What do you mean? It's throwing an error

Comment: It didn't throw any exception to my side! just copied ur code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was to remove the

```
response.end();
```

It works fine now.